# I can't use pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, error-handling, pyinstaller

I tried to use pyinstaller by typing `pyinstaller myfile.py` and it didn't work
I got this error

```
pyinstaller : The term 'pyinstaller' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pyinstaller
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: You already said in a response to a now-deleted answer that you ran `pip install pyinstaller`. Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: I have the very same problem, working on Windows 11.
Here you call python commands by typing py or py -3 -m no normal python or python3 commands work.
But pyinstaller doesn't work with any of them :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're encountering issues with running PyInstaller even after installing it, it's possible that the Python Scripts directory isn't properly added to your system's PATH variable.

Here's another approach to directly run PyInstaller without relying on the PATH variable:

### **Using Python's `-m` Flag** :

Python's `-m` flag allows you to run a module as a script, bypassing the need for the script's directory to be in the PATH.

Try running PyInstaller using this method:

```bash
python -m PyInstaller --onefile rename.py
```

Replace `rename.py` with the actual name and path of your Python script.

This command invokes PyInstaller as a module directly using Python, which should work even if PyInstaller's directory is not in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue today and I found that typing `PyInstaller` instead of `pyinstaller` (case-sensitive) helps fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

**Your Error** "*pyinstaller : The term '**pyinstaller**' is not recognized as the name of a **cmdlet***" Looks like your trying to execute in **Powershell** not **Python**.

To run **Python** in **PowerShell**. You can just do python .py to run the script.

```
python myfile.py
```

**PyInstaller** is available on **PyPI**. You can install it through **pip**.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Create **Executable** from **Python Script** using **Pyinstaller**

```
pyinstaller --onefile pythonScriptName.py
```

More Information About Creating **Executables** from **Python Script** using **Pyinstaller** Can Be Found Here https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: `pyinstaller` is _supposed_ to be run from a terminal like PowerShell, at least in this use case. You even show that as an example in your answer. OP already ran `pip install pyinstaller` (that was determined in a response to a now-deleted answer). I believe the issue is that PyInstaller isn't properly in OP's `$Env:PATH` though I'm not exactly sure how that's supposed to work on Windows, especially if OP is not using a virtual environment.